# Does JSON-LD structured data work with Google Plus shared website link snippets too?

Tags: microdata, rich-snippets, json-ld, google-plus

I just recently switched my [Web ID card (i.e. my primary web profile) website](https://card.jamesandersonjr.com), over from Microdata to JSON-LD to get better, more fine-grained control over the structured data [appearance](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fcard.jamesandersonjr.com), on [Google Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool), and subsequently on [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=james%20anderson%20jr%20web%20id%20card).

Now I wonder, does JSON-LD structured data also work with Google+ (Google Plus) shared website link snippets, or will I have to switch back to Microdata to produce a rich snippet when sharing my site on on Google+?

Comment: Did you find documentation for the feature?

Comment: Just [this](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data), touting JSON-LD as the _"recommended"_ type of structured data.

Comment: I have json-ld for Article in <head>, And I have schema.org microdata for images in body (inside the article content itself). Google plus is reading microdata for sharing and not json-ld. https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/